# How to query limit with offset in Scylla and Go

Tags: go, cassandra, scylla

Using `gocql` or `gocqlx`, there's no example to fetch nth page:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (
    id    BIGINT, -- unique using distributed synchronous counter (redis-like), since Scylla doesn't support RETURNING on counter
    email TEXT, -- to enforce uniqueness
    PRIMARY KEY(email)
);
CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS ON users(id);
```

Query function:

```
func QueryRows(cql string) (res []M.SX) { // M.SX is map[string]interface{}
    q := Database.Query(cql) // database is the connection to scylla
    defer q.Release()
    res = []M.SX{}
    iter := q.Iter()
    for {
        row := M.SX{}
        if !iter.MapScan(row) {
            break
        }
        res = append(res, row)
    }
    return
}
```

Is there no easy but with good performance (without `ALLOW FILTERING`) to fetch nth-page (order by `email` or `id`)?

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE id > 44 LIMIT 10 ALLOW FILTERING; 
-- eg. 44 is last id of current page
```

Answer (score 3):

Hi did you try token based pagination?

Example from scylladb/gocqlx

https://github.com/scylladb/gocqlx/blob/master/example_test.go#L168

Comment: @Kokizzu Yes, but not in the way you're thinking of it.  If you specify a token range (hashed token value of your partition key) with your query, you can iterate through all of the ranges.

Comment: so, the simpler way is: `SELECT * FROM users WHERE token(id)>token(?) LIMIT 10 ` ? but in my case, `id` is not the `PARTITION KEY`, it's just indexed column

Comment: The client drivers normally support automatic token-based pagination (eg java cassandra driver).

Comment: `token(id) > token(lastIdOnPreviousPage)` is a bit simplified. If you have 20 rows with the same partition-key (and different cluster-keys) and page-size 10, the last 10 rows will never be returned. Also, it is possible for 2 id's to hash to the same token. You might need `token(id) >= token(lastIdOnPreviousPage)` and then skip over rows until you pass lastRowOnPreviousPage (match on full PK: both PartionKey + ClusterKey).